# JavaScriptのModuleのimportでエラー

Tags: javascript

Javascriptのモジュールをimportしようとすると、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

test.js ( moduleファイル ↓)

```
function crazyman() {
      alert("You idiot!");
}
export crazyman();
```

crazy.js (importしたファイル↓)

```
import {crazyman} from "test.js";
crazyman();
```

easy_sample.html (HTMLファイル↓)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ja" dir="ltr">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript sample</title>
   </head>
   <body >
    <script src="crazy.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

三つのファイルはすべて同じディレクトリに存在しています。ブラウザはfirefoxです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

モジュールではないJavaScriptコードでは`import`が使えません。

HTMLでJavaScriptコードをモジュールとして扱うには、`script` 要素に `type="module"` を指定します。

```html
<script src="crazy.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし修正すると今度は「クロスオリジン要求をブロックしました」というエラーが発生してしまいました...

Comment: file:// だと動きません。https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts

Comment: ローカルでは出来ないんですね...ありがとうございました。